# Having a different image shown on each Marker hover on a Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps, mapbox

Currently I am using ReactMapGL as my Map component. Here I'm using its HTMLOverlay feature to bring a full screen popup whenever I hover above a marker. I have currently set different image data for all my markers, but when I hover over the marker I only get the 1 same image for all of them. How do I get the marker to show its respective image?

I've added a codesandbox for better reference:
https://codesandbox.io/s/full-popup-mapbox-stackoverflow-forked-p8934?file=/src/App.js:1540-1551

Here's my code:

```
<ReactMapGL
          {...viewport}
          mapboxApiAccessToken={YOURMAPBOXTOKEN}
          mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9"
          onViewportChange={(viewport) => {
            setViewport(viewport);
          }}
        >
          {posts &&
            posts.map((item) => (
              <HTMLOverlay
                redraw={(props) => {
                  {
                    /* todo: grow animation from center */
                  }
                  return (
                    <div
                      style={{
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)",
                        width: isPopupShown ? props.width : 0,
                        height: isPopupShown ? props.height : 0,
                        transition: "all .2s ease-in-out",
                        transform: "scale(1.1)",
                        overflow: "hidden",
                        alignItems: "center",
                        justifyContent: "center"
                      }}
                    >
                      {/* todo: text/content position */}
                      <img src={item.backgroundImage} alt="bg" />
                    </div>
                  );
                }}
              />
            ))}

          {posts &&
            posts.map((item) => (
              <Marker
                key={item.id}
                latitude={item.latitude}
                longitude={item.longitude}
              >
                <button className="marker-btn">
                  <img
                    style={{
                      width: 48,
                      height: 48
                    }}
                    onMouseEnter={() => {
                      setSelectedProperty(item);
                      setIsPopupShown(true);
                    }}
                    onMouseOut={() => {
                      setSelectedProperty(null);
                      setIsPopupShown(false);
                    }}
                    alt="Marker"
                  />
                </button>
              </Marker>
            ))}
        </ReactMapGL>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to selectively render the HTMLOverlap for whatever pin is currently hovered over.

```
   {selectedProperty && (
            <HTMLOverlay
              redraw={(props) => {
                {
                  /* todo: grow animation from center */
                }
                return (
                  <div
                    style={{
                      width: isPopupShown ? props.width : 0,
                      height: isPopupShown ? props.height : 0,
                      transition: "all .2s ease-in-out",
                      transform: "scale(1.1)",
                      overflow: "hidden",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      justifyContent: "center",
                      backgroundImage: `url(${selectedProperty.backgroundImage})`,
                      backgroundSize: "cover",
                      backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
                    }}
                  >
                    {/* some text */}
                  </div>
                );
              }}
            />
          )}
```

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/full-popup-mapbox-stackoverflow-forked-xsui0?file=/src/App.js) with working example.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted. I had 1 more doubt regarding Mapbox frontend if you could kindly check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68827410/formatting-the-style-of-mapbox-component