# Formatting the style of Mapbox component

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am currently using React as Frontend and ReactMapGL as my map component and I'm trying to style it so that all my continents have different colors. I tried styling in all the different templates provided, But I can only change the water and land color in http://studio.mapbox.com . Is it possible to make this change happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to overlay a continent layer on your map and then conditionally style it based on your own color/continent mapping logic.

You can get the data (geojson) for the continent layer by searching for it.

```js
  const continentLayer = {
    id: "continents",
    type: "fill",
    source: {
      type: "geojson",
      data: continents
    },
    paint: {
      "fill-color": [
        "match",
        ["get", "CONTINENT"],
        "Asia",
        "red",
        "Europe",
        "Green",
        /* default */ "yellow"
      ]
    }
  };

  <Layer {...continentLayer} />
```

Here's a codesandbox with a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/color-xd1cw?file=/src/App.js (also take a look at continent.json)

Comment: Yes this works, but currently I have the map set to zoom: 0.8 to have the entire map fit into my full screen but this brings up additional maps to the side. Is there anyway to have only 1 map that is fit to the center of the screen?

Comment: @JayModi setRenderWorldCopies to 1

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/render-world-copies/

Comment: so I tried adding `setRenderWorldCopies={1}` to my <ReactMapGL component but it still dint work out

Comment: @Manish Hey thanks for the help, could you kindly also check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69053285/spacing-out-markers-in-map-component